# Django Form does not render

Tags: python, django

my Django form does not render, other forms in the project work without an issue, I am just lost

This form is supposed to display in template file product_review.html that then is displayed through {% include %} to products.html

I think I should point out that this is a separate Django app

My Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from ecommerce.models import Item

STAR_CHOICES = (
    ('0','0'),
    ('1','1'),
    ('2','2'),
    ('3','3'),
    ('4','4'),
    ('5','5'),
)

# Create your models here.
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    review_content = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
    star_score = models.CharField(choices=STAR_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    item = models.ForeignKey('ecommerce.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My Form:

```
from django import forms
from ecommerce.models import Item
from .models import Review

STAR_CHOICES = (
    ('0','0'),
    ('1','1'),
    ('2','2'),
    ('3','3'),
    ('4','4'),
    ('5','5'),
)

class AddReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    star_score = forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=STAR_CHOICES)
    review_content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'rows': 4
    })) 
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user','timestamp','item']
```

My View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Review
from .forms import AddReviewForm
from ecommerce.models import Item
from django.shortcuts import redirect


# Create your views here.
def AddProductReviewView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    form = AddReviewForm(self.request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST"
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.item = item
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("ecommerce:product", kwargs={
                'slug':slug
            }))
    context = {
        'form':form
        'item':item
    }
    return render(self.request,'product_review.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be a class, and it needs to provide a `get` method which includes your form so that it can display it when you first view the page;

```
# Create your views here.
class AddProductReviewView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': AddReviewForm()
        }
        return render(self.request, 'product_review.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.get('slug')
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
        form = AddReviewForm(self.request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.item = item
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("ecommerce:product", kwargs={
                'slug': slug
            }))

        context = {
            'form': form
            'item': item
        }
        return render(self.request,'product_review.html')
```

Comment: That still does the same, I have checked and output the form in bash and its displaying proper HTML. The view seems to be the issue

Comment: Ok now i see my problem. I haven't mapped my View into urls, now I need to figure out how to pass 2 views into this one page

Comment: @MateuszDelegacz You can't have 2 views on one page. Why do you think you need 2 views on a page?